# Boolean expression simplification - is my solution correct?

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have this boolean expression:

(x′ ∧ y ∧ z′) ∨ (x′ ∧ z) ∨ (x ∧ y)

and I simplified it using K-maps to this:

(y ∧ z′) ∨ x

Is my solution  correct? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't analyze it but you can help you can easily verify your solution using an online [Karnaugh map](http://www.32x8.com/).

Comment: No. If `x` is 1, the original reduces to `y`, while your simplification is 1 regardless of `y`.

Comment: The correct answer is $$(x'\land z)\lor y$$

Answer (score 1):

I used [Stanford's truth table generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) to get:

```
x   y   z   ((¬x ∧ (y ∧ ¬z)) ∨ ((¬x ∧ z) ∨ (x ∧ y)))
F   F   F   F
F   F   T   T
F   T   F   T
F   T   T   T
T   F   F   F
T   F   T   F
T   T   F   T
T   T   T   T
```

Now, we know the value from x, y, and z to the result, automatically generated--no mistakes.

From here, you could opt to draw a karnaugh map, or simply look at the results.

Here's a k-map:

```
  y'z' y'z yz yz'
x  0    0  1  1
x' 0    1  1  1
```

If you notice, wherever $y$ is $1$, we get $1$.  So:

$$y$$

However, there is one exception, and that's $x'y'z$, so:

$$y + x'y'z$$

Let's double check our work...

```
x   y   z   (y ∨ (¬x ∧ (¬y ∧ z)))
F   F   F   F
F   F   T   T
F   T   F   T
F   T   T   T
T   F   F   F
T   F   T   F
T   T   F   T
T   T   T   T
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my solution correct? $(y ∧ z′) ∨ x$

No.   You have this boolean expression:

$$\begin{align}\quad&(x′ ∧ y ∧ z′) ∨ (x′ ∧ z) ∨ (x ∧ y)\\=~&(y ∧ x′ ∧ z′) ∨ (y ∧ x) ∨ (x′ ∧ z)&&\text{by commutation}\\=~&&&\text{by distributing out the common term}\\=~&&&\\=~&&&\\=~&y\lor(x'\land z)&&\end{align}$$

Fill in the missing details.